# OnePlus 8T battery capacity

Tags: battery

Using the AccuBattery app I'm told that the design capacity of the battery is 4500 mAh, but after 3 significant charging sessions the current capacity is 2095 and has never reached 50% of the design capacity. I've tried contacting AccuBattery and OnePlus to see if I should be trying to exchange this brand new phone given this report. I haven't gotten an answer yet. Does anyone else have any info about OnePlus 8T *actual* battery capacity or how to deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer from AccuBattery support (OnePlus 8T has a dual battery apparently):

> Unfortunately there's no solution for this at the moment as the system
> isn't reporting the values in the correct manner. It looks like more
> devices with dual batteries have this issue but we currently don't
> have these devices to test with so we can't figure out the exact
> underlying problem and build a workaround for it, but the most
> apparent issue is that the device reports half of the charge current.
> The health estimate can still be calculated if you do a manual
> benchmark like this:
> https://accubattery.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213575425-How-to-manually-benchmark-your-battery-health
> but the maximum you will get is half the design capacity so you will
> need to multiply the mAh estimate by 2 (or change the design capacity
> so it's half the original value) and make the assumption that the two
> batteries are used at the same rate; which is probably not what's
> actually happening (one battery might be used to charged the other for
> example).

Comment: you can mark this as an answer, while there is not better solution